# tesseract-ocr use ascii only?

Tags: .net, tesseract

I have been using tesseract-ocr (in .NET) which has been working well. The images i feed it are ascii only (A-z0-9). Is there a way i can tell it not to use special characters?

Comment: It's got an active forum, good place to ask: http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Victor's answer:
If you know you will only encounter a subset of the characters available in the language, such as only digits, you can use the `tessedit_char_whitelist` configuration variable. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/f2688151401c1a4ec5a7b16994bfd5ffe0da274c/tess3/FAQ-Old.md#how-do-i-recognize-only-digits) for an example.

In my case, I set it thusly:

```golang
client.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~")
```

Comment: This works perfectly, it got rid of odd chars that seemed to have been randomly inserted and made them into the correct letters.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a new thread](http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/browse_thread/thread/c8931a3db5d1b4ed#) about this question over at the Google forum linked above. The first answer concludes that it probably isn't possible.

As far as I know, this is correct, if you're using the language data files that are packaged with Tesseract. You can, however, very easily limit the output characters if you're [training on your own box files](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract). It's practically automatic: if `unicharset_extractor` doesn't find any non-ASCII characters in the box files, you'll never see non-ASCII characters in the output.

I was similarly frustrated by all the [interpuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) and other [unusual characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a4/index.htm) in my output when I first started using Tesseract, and training on my own box files solved the problem. You can even use the Tesseract [training data](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=boxtiff-2.01.eng.tar.gz&can=2&q=) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

use the tessedit_char_whitelist config option.